# How to configure the actual setting for localhost?

Tags: hadoop

My core-site.xml is configured like this.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Now, when I enter 'start-all.cmd' in the command prompt, I see the services startup and I enter this 'localhost:9000' into my web browser, and I get an error message.  When I enter this 'localhost:8088' into the web browser, I see the Hadoop cluster, which is up and running just fine.  It seems like the core-site.xml is ignored, and the 'localhost:8088' is picked up from somewhere else, but I can't find it.  Can someone give me a quick and dirty description of how this actually works?  I already Googled for an answer, but I didn't seen anything useful about this.

Answer (score 0):

format name node using this :

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

For more information:

Follow installation steps from this Site. It is working perfectly fine.

http://pingax.com/install-hadoop2-6-0-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Where do I run it from?  I opened the cmd window and popped it in there.  That gives me this error: 'hdfs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.